# Xcode 6 Beta doesn't pick up code signing certificate

Tags: xcode

I downloaded Xcode 6 Beta and installed it on my Mac side by side with my original Xcode 5. While I have no problem in seeing my code signing certificate in Xcode 5 there is no way for me to get Xcode 6 to pick up it. Any trick out there? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 is only in its first beta so very much still under NDA.
Best to check with the [Apple DEV Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios8_beta)

I haven't tried signing certificate just yet, but it could be locked out until a newer version of the beta .....

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your quick turnaround. Now the problem is resolved and it might be due to the connectivity issue to the Apple server according to engineers here.

Answer (score 0):

While I went to seek help from Apple engineers here at WWDC the code signing certificate mysteriously showed up in Xcode 6. As explained by Apple's engineer the problem might be attributed to some network issue earlier here. Now I have certificate in, Xcode 6 complained about missing private keys to it and it is resolved by revoking and re-requesting the developer certificate.

Comment: How do you find time to be on SO when you are at WWDC?? :-)

Comment: Nice. How come I didn't recognize it :)